# How to create this extruded piece from a rectangle?

Tags: modeling

I have to solve this problem. How can i extrude that extra piece in the middle. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with an "Inset" operation (<kbd>I</kbd>) to create the geometry for the center hole, then move it slightly on the Y and Z axis and then eventually remove the face in the middle of the inset. Further detailing steps (such as solidification and bevelling) are of course necessary but that should give you a starting point.

If that's not what you were after, please clarify the question. I'm assuming you want to model the pictured piece in Blender.